# If a game is pulled out of app store, what happens to it's installation in my mobile?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, app-store

If a game is pulled out of app store, what happens to it's installation in my mobile or laptop?

The question came to my mind after reading the news about upcoming pull out of Flapping Bird.

Comment: and may i know ..how would you pull out from app store?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about app store distribution, and not programming.

Comment: All of the apps stores can reach into devices and force-delete apps. It's happened before, it'll happen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of Apple appstore, the app will stay on your device. You can even backup to iTunes and reinstall later.

Some cases you can still find the app under purchased tab so you can install it later from *cloud*

But there are lot of grey areas with apple. Not all the apps you have purchased are listed there.